# Change network drive label by command line

Tags: windows, command-line, network-shares

I have just create a new network driver by command line using

```
net use
```

But when I try to change this drive's label by command line using `label` command, an error occurs:

```
C:\>label X: Shared
Parameters not compatible.
```

How can I change this by command line?

Comment: Try this solution: http://superuser.com/a/795473/248359 it works great

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The label command will only work for a physical drive.  To rename a mapped network drive, you need to rename it using My Computer on a machine.  To automate this for use across many computers, the new label will be saved as a registry key.  Look for the following key:

```
HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\MountPoints2
```

Export the "_LabelFromReg" key for the drive in question and import the key on the other machines before your "net use" command.

Comment: I suppose he could use the `REG` command to script it.

Comment: What "_LabelFromReg" key are you talking about? What do I have to write into MountPoints2?

Answer (score 1):

Another perhaps slightly faster method is using Powershell:

```
$a = New-Object -ComObject shell.application

$a.NameSpace( "X:\" ).self.name = "YOURLABEL"
```

Comment: Doesn't seem to work? Give me an error that `name` cannot be found on this object

Comment: No errors, but has no effect, the label does not change.