# Why does this change the name on mapped drive M and G, not just M

Tags: windows-registry, vbscript, mapped-drive

I wrote this vbs (included below) based on the answer here: [Override mapped drive name using .bat script?](https://superuser.com/questions/461909/override-mapped-drive-name-using-bat-script)

As stated in my title, this code is updating the label for drive M and G, but should only update drive M. Both go to the appropriate (different) location.

```
' rename network map.vbs
' VBScript to map a network drive.
' Authors Guy Thomas and Barry Maybury
' Version 1.4 – April 2010
' April 2019, Gary Baddorf - function-ized it
' —————————————-
 Option Explicit
NameDrive "\\ad.hs.net\shared", "M:", "CH (\\ad.hs.net\shared\)"

WScript.Quit

Sub NameDrive(strRemotePath, strDriveLetter, strNewName)
    Dim objNetwork, objShell, err
    Set objShell = CreateObject("Shell.Application")
    Set objNetwork = CreateObject("WScript.Network") 

    ' Section to map the network drive
    On Error Resume Next
    objNetwork.RemoveNetworkDrive strDriveLetter
    If Err.Number <> 0 Then
      WScript.Echo "Error: " & Err.Description
      Err.Clear
    End If 
    objNetwork.MapNetworkDrive strDriveLetter, strRemotePath

    ' Section which actually (re)names the Mapped Drive
    objShell.NameSpace(strDriveLetter).Self.Name = strNewName

    Wscript.Echo "Check "& strDriveLetter & " for " & strNewName
    objNetwork.Dispose()
    objNetwork = Nothing
    objShell.Dispose()
    objShell = Nothing
End Sub
```

Note, I can switch in this line and it does nothing:

```
NameDrive "\\ad.hs.net\shared", "G:", "CH2"
```

Additional info. I can watch the MountPoints2 in Registry Editor for each networked path and the _LabelFromReg value is correct for each drive. I also deleted them and ran the script again without success.

Comment: The answer you copied the script from also says: If this doesn't work, add a \. So... what if you change G: to G:\?

Comment: Sorry yes, I tried G:\ and M:\. There was no difference using that on my system.

Comment: I would guess that it's a matter of the folder not completely mapping before attempting to access it with the objShell.Namespace method. Have you tried either testing for a return value in the MapNetworkDrive call (even if you discard it), inserting a delay, or assigning the NameSpace call to an object and performing the Self.Name only if that object isn't null or invalid?

Answer (score 0):

Some time after having this issue and giving up I restarted my computer. Of course the drives have the right names now. I'm not going to mess with it to see if running the script again would have the same issue. I feel dumb for not restarting earlier, but that's never been an issue for me when using `net use` or registry edits.